# specify type of delegate parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, action, trygetvalue

im trying to use `TryGetValue`.

to Invoke a delegate inside `Method` i use dictionary to select one delegate and then Invoke it.

the dictionary type is

```
Dictionary<string, Action<Mesh>> _meshActions;
```

and the action type is

```
Action<Mesh>
```

So here it seems i can not declare `action` in delegate parameter correctly.

```
        Method(null, "mesh", ( action => //How to specify type of action
        {
            _meshActions.TryGetValue(_reader.LocalName, out action);

            try { action(mesh); }
            catch 
            {
                //do nothing 
            }
        }));
```

Compiler expects `out` be type of `Action<Mesh>` but how can i set the `action` type?

before using `TryGetValue` i used dictionary normally

but because sometimes i got error for **Key not found** so i decided to use `TryGetValue`

this is the code without TryGetValue and works fine if all Keys find.

```
Method(null, "mesh", () => _meshActions[_reader.LocalName](mesh));
```

Edit: note that `action` is nothing outside delegate. i just want to send parameter inside TryGetValue and use its resault.

and here is the `Method`

```
    private static void Method(string enterElement, string exitElement, Action loadElement)
    {
        while (_reader.Read())
        {
            if (StateElement(State.Enter, enterElement))
            {
                loadElement.Invoke();
            }
            else if (StateElement(State.Exit, exitElement))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide declaration `Method`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action` needs to be declared locally in the delegate, not as a parameter.

```
    Method(null, "mesh", ( () => //How to specify type of action
    {
        Action<Mesh> action;
        _meshActions.TryGetValue(_reader.LocalName, out action);

        try { action(mesh); }
        catch 
        {
            //do nothing 
        }
    }));
```

Comment: No, it's not dynamic.  The signature of your `Method` method specifies that it expects an `Action`, plain and simple.  That means that it expects a delegate with this signature: `() => { ... }`.  No parameters and no return value.  Where is the confusion?  EDIT: I must have dreamed there was a comment there :)

Comment: oh thanks i got it. i dont know why i forget simple things when i get in deep coding. delegates are forgetful for me.thanks for the answer!Edit : haha i asked and i guess it was stupid question because of late answer and ...umm sorry for that!